# Scatterplot in R with ggplot2:

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, scatter-plot

I have the following data set.

```
> y
                  DF           GE
2006-12-21 -0.0004659447 -0.009960682
2006-12-22 -0.0009323238 -0.005295208
2006-12-26 -0.0032661785  0.003726377
2006-12-27  0.0042131332  0.002121453
2006-12-28 -0.0009323238 -0.008203228
2006-12-29 -0.0135313109 -0.007203842
```

When I fortify it becomes this.

```
> fortify(y, melt=TRUE)
    Index     Series         Value
1  2006-12-21     DF -0.0004659447
2  2006-12-22     DF -0.0009323238
3  2006-12-26     DF -0.0032661785
4  2006-12-27     DF  0.0042131332
5  2006-12-28     DF -0.0009323238
6  2006-12-29     DF -0.0135313109
7  2006-12-21     GE -0.0099606815
8  2006-12-22     GE -0.0052952078
9  2006-12-26     GE  0.0037263774
10 2006-12-27     GE  0.0021214532
11 2006-12-28     GE -0.0082032284
12 2006-12-29     GE -0.0072038420
```

Now I would like to run a scatterplot in ggplot2. At the moment, the function I use is the following.

```
x <- fortify(x, melt=TRUE)
ggplot(data=x) +
geom_point(size=10, aes(x=Series, y=Value, colour=Index))
```

But what I really want is a scatter plot with the values of DF and GE to be the coordinates on X and Y axis and for the date to be shown by colour.

I simply cannot work out how to amend the data structure to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column("date") %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = DF, y = GE)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = date))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "                 DF           GE
2006-12-21 -0.0004659447 -0.009960682
2006-12-22 -0.0009323238 -0.005295208
2006-12-26 -0.0032661785  0.003726377
2006-12-27  0.0042131332  0.002121453
2006-12-28 -0.0009323238 -0.008203228
2006-12-29 -0.0135313109 -0.007203842", header = T)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `fortify()`. I would keep your data the way it is and do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

y %>%
rownames_to_column() %>%   
ggplot(aes(x = DF, y = GE, color = index) + 
geom_point()
```